# What is the difference between static files and embedded application resources in Ktor?

Tags: ktor

I'm reading the ktor [documentation on serving static content](https://ktor.io/docs/eap/serving-static-content.html#embedded-application-resources) and it's not clear to me what the difference between `files("css")` and `resources("css")` is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `static` method is equivalent to the `route` method so it just creates a path route in the routing tree.

The `files` method allows serving all static files from the provided path (directory) from a local filesystem. Relative paths will be resolved using the current working directory.

The `resources` method does the same as the `files` method except that it allows serving static files from the classpath.

Here is an example:

```
// Assume that current working directory is /home/user/project
embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080) {
    routing {
        // This route will be resolved if a request path starts with /assets/
        static("assets") {
            // For the request path /assets/style.css the file /home/user/project/css/style.css will be served
            files("./css")
            // It's the same as above
            files("css")
            // For the request path /assets/data.txt the file /absolute/path/to/data.txt will be served
            files("/absolute/path/to")

            // For the request path /assets/style.css the file <resources>/css/style.css will be served
            // where <resources> is the embedded resource directory
            resources("css")
        }
    }
}.start(wait = true)
```

Comment: Thanks! I got it now!